# Broken SwiftUI animation when using TabView

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, tabview, swiftui-geometryeffect

I have a working animation in a SwiftUI view, which breaks, when I put that view into a `TabView`, go to the other tab and come back. How can I fix it?

My view is more complex, but I boiled it down to the following:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct AnimationTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Tab 1")
                    }
                Text("Content 2")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Tab 2")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.move()
            }) {
                Text("Move")
            }

            ZStack() {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
                if viewModel.moved {
                    RectView()
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: namespace, properties: .frame)
                        .animation(Animation.default.speed(0.5))
                        .offset(x: 0, y: -130)

                } else {
                    RectView()
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: namespace, properties: .frame)
                        .animation(Animation.default.speed(0.5))
                        .offset(x: 0, y: 130)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RectView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 30, alignment: .center)
    }
}


final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var moved = false

    func move() {
        moved = !moved
    }
}
```

Here is an screen recording of that code. The `RectView` animates smoothly up and down when tapping `Move`. After switching to `Tab 2` and going back, the first time I tap `Move`, it jumps without animation. The next taps are animated again.

[image: Animation]

In reality the view model is more complex. The state (in this case: `moved`) is changed some time after hitting the button. Some work is done on a background thread and then the state change is triggered on the main thread. This is why I can't move the animation into the `Button` action.

Also the view is more complex. The `RectView` is removed from deep in the view hierarchy and added somewhere entirely else.

The method `func animation(_ animation: Animation?)` is deprecated in iOS 15. The problem is already existing in iOS 14 forever. I also tried removing the `animation` modifiers and put the `moved = !moved` into an `withAnimation { }` block. Still the same result.

How could I fix that while keeping the `TabView`?

Comment: Clarification: In my original code I have about 40 RectViews (actually they are more complex than a rect). Only one or two of them are moving when the state changes. They are deeply nested in a hierarchy of ZStacks, VStacks, GeometryReaders etc. This is why I need to work with matchedGeometryEffect and offset.

Comment: Hi, I would really like to hear your final solution as I am having the same issue. I understand the reason that TabViews preserve their states and so the animation will be restarted but also uses its older state. I solved it by adding a flag inside the onAppear so that it will be only called once, but this seems a little bit hacky to me. Did you find a better way? Thx in advance :-)

Answer (score -1):

You had some bad coding issue, here the working code, also you do not need `matchedGeometryEffect` here:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct AnimationTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                ContentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Tab 1")
                    }
                Text("Content 2")
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Tab 2")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: { viewModel.moved.toggle() }) {
                Text("Move")
            }

            ZStack() {

                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
                
                RectView()
                    .offset(x: 0, y: viewModel.moved ? -130 : 130)
                    .animation(Animation.default.speed(0.5), value: viewModel.moved)
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RectView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 30)
    }
}


final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var moved: Bool = false
}
```